# jquery ajax and after is duplicating the results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a load more button, which when clicked it displays the next 4 items, by doing an ajax call.

However, sometimes (for no apparent reason), the content is duplicated and returned twice, even though when I alert the results, there's only 1. This also happens when you double click the button.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
/* load more */
    $('.load-more').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        $('.pagination-holder').fadeOut(250,function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });

        var start = $(this).data('start'),
            limit = $(this).data('limit'),
            page = $(this).data('page'),
            type = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url:'/index.php?route=news/news/getnext&start=4&limit=4&page=2',
            method:'GET',
            data:{start:start,limit:limit,page:page},
            dataType:'json'
        }).done(function(data){

            var html = '';

            html +='<div class="row next" style="display:none">';
            $.each(data.newss,function(i,news){
                html +='<div class="col-md-3 pt30">';
                html +='    <div class="image mb30"><a href="'+news.href+'"><img src="'+news.image+'" alt="'+news.title+'" class="responsive" /></a></div>';
                html +='    <div class="text">';
                html +='        <h3><a href="'+news.href+'">'+news.title+'</a></h3>';
                html +='        <p class="date mb5">'+news.date+'</p>';
                html +='        <p class="mb30">'+news.description+'</p>';
                html +='        <a href="'+news.href+'" class="btn mb30">Read</a>';
                html +='    </div>';
                html +='</div>';
                if ((i+1) % 4 === 0) {
                    html +='<div class="clear"></div>';
                }
            });
            html +='</div>';

            //alert(html); /* when I alert this, it displays one row, as it should do, but when i don't alert this, it can append duplicates */

            $('#'+type+'-list').find('.row').after(html).ready(function(){
                $('.row.next').fadeIn(500).removeClass('next');
            });

        });
    });
```

I've seen similar questions throughout stackoverflow and I've tried to solve the issue, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hey you can use my same answer on it:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery isn't getting dynamically updated data from button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788916/jquery-isnt-getting-dynamically-updated-data-from-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can use my same answer on it:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788916/jquery-isnt-getting-dynamically-updated-data-from-button
```