# jquery isn't getting dynamically updated data from button

Tags: jquery, click, onclicklistener

I've created a button, which updates the values of itself, and when clicked on (again), jquery isn't picking up the updated values..

Before first click:

```
<a href="news" data-start="2" data-limit="2" data-page="2" class="btn load-more">Load more</a>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.load-more',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var start   = $(this).data('start'),
            limit   = $(this).data('limit'),
            page    = $(this).data('page'),
            type    = $(this).attr('href');

        alert( start+' '+limit+' '+page );

        $.ajax({
            url:'/index.php?route=news/news/getnext&start=4&limit=4&page=2',
            method:'GET',
            data:{start:start,limit:limit,page:page},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){

                .... doing stuff ....

                if(data.pagination === true){
                    $('.load-more').attr('data-start',data.start).attr('data-limit',data.limit).attr('data-page',data.next);
                } else {
                    $('.load-more').fadeOut(250,function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                }

            }
        })(data);
    });
```

This alerts "2 2 2" as expected.

The updated button (after the first click):

```
<a href="news" data-start="4" data-limit="2" data-page="3" class="btn load-more">Load more</a>
```

Then I click the button again, and it still alerts "2 2 2", instead of "4 2 3", which the button was updated to..

Any ideas on this? I can't seem to get it working, I've tried the basic click function and also delegate but it's not working as expected.

Comment: As explained in [the `.data()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/), "The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).". So if you want to update those values, use `.data()` to both retrieve *and* set the values, or use `.attr()` to both retrieve *and* set the values. Don't mix `.data()` and `.attr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After update the below code:

```
 <a href="news" data-start="4" data-limit="2" data-page="3" class="btn load-more">Load more</a>

    $(document).on('click','.load-more',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var start   = $(this).attr('data-start');
        limit   = $(this).attr('data-limit');
        page    = $(this).attr('data-page');


    alert( start+' '+limit+' '+page );
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Is there any reason why it didn't like $(this).data('start') etc?

Comment: Yes because you were not getting its attribute like I do now.

Comment: Any way thanks, if my answer is helpful than please mark tick on it :)

Comment: Please follow me on my blog developerajay.blogspot.com